# How to list/view all created resources on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way  list/view(graphically?) all created resources on amazon? All the db's users, pools etc.

The best way I can think of is to run each of the cli `aws <resource> ls` commands in a bash file.

What would be great would be to have a graphical tool that showed all the relationships. Is anyone aware of such a tool?

**UPDATE**

I decided to make my own start on this, currently its just on the cli, but might move to graphical output. Help needed!

https://github.com/QuantumInformation/aws-x-ray

Comment: I would be highly interested in a tool like this too. I have no idea if there is such a tool, but there is certainly none in the AWS console. I sometimes try out services and also sometimes forget to delete them again. This gave me some nice and expensive surprises... :-S If there would be a tool to monitor all services that you run, this wouldn't happen because you wouldn't lose oversight. Btw. I contacted AWS support because of this and they couldn't help me.

Comment: @Otterfinger I've started an OS project to tackle this.

Comment: awesome! please ping me if I can help.

Comment: @Otterfinger check out https://github.com/QuantumInformation/aws-x-ray

Comment: **See Also**: [Is there a way to list all resources in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44391817/1366033)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to easily list all services created on AWS.

Each service has a set of API calls and will typically have `Describe*` calls that can list resources. However, these commands would need to be issued to each service individually and they typically have different syntax.

There are third-party services (eg [Kumolus](http://kumolus.com/)) that offer functionality to list and visualize services but they are typically focussed on Amazon EC2 and Amazon VPC-based services. They definitely would not go 'into' a database to list DB users, but they would show Amazon RDS instances.