# AWS CLI command for tags editor console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I use my https://resources.console.aws.amazon.com/r/tags page to find all resources in a given region that have my name in them, since the cleanup scripts I use don't seem to cleanup 100% of the resources I create while testing deployments. I select a region, All resource types, I leave the tag filter blank, and enter my name as filter and bingo! I can even navigate to the actual resource to delete it, excellent.

I would like to do this from the command line instead of console, so I looked at `aws resourcegroupstaggingapi`:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources
```

This retourns a whole pile of resources, providing the ARN for each one and the tags. The list of resources returned is close to that in the console but not identical: some resources are missing, and it finds some that do not appear in the console.

So forget about the Tags console because the above indicates it may not show everything, but also forget about resourcegroupstaggingapi since it doesn't get everything; what is correct way to get all AWS resources in a given region?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391817/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-resources-in-aws, the answers to which suggest that there is no standard way to list absolutely all resources for an AWS account (though some open-source projects exist that try to do that).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to list all resources in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391817/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-resources-in-aws)