# How do I lower the cost of AWS on iOS App?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I am trying to understand my AWS Cost Report. I am developing a social media app that uses AWS for database and storage. This month's cost was 250$ and I am the only user of the app. Is this normal? My plan was to release the app and get more users onboard but I am very scared of this now.

Services that I am using:

- AppSync/DynamoDB.
- S3
- AWSCloudFront
- Cognito

I have 2 tables on DynamoDB (AppSync).  I converted them to global tables so people in other countries could use the app too. I chose 3 regions : Asia/Tokyo, EU/London and US/California.

I don't understand well the difference on the costs by EC2 and relational database service

Do you have any suggestions to lower the costs? Will be enough if I remove the global tables?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There may be a better stackexchange for this type of question so don't be surprised if this gets closed and someone links you elsewhere, but: why do you need to be deployed in multiple regions? Is the latency back to a single region like US-east or EU causing issues in your app? Do you also need all of those services?

Comment: I first started to develop this app in Japan and configured all my services there. Now I am in Spain and the app stop working so I had to change my table's region from Asia/Tokyo to Europe, and I also included US

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your cost graphs, most of the cost comes from EC2 and RDS, but both of these services aren't listed in the list of services you use for your app.
You should check the AWS regions `eu-west-1` (Ireland) and `ap-northeast-1` (Tokyo) in your AWS account for resources like running EC2 instances, EBS volumes/snapshots and RDS instances and shut them down or delete them if you don't need them.

If you struggle finding the resources, you can also use the Tag Editor of AWS Resource Groups to get a list of the existing resources as explained in the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48288505/4779904

Comment: thank you, I think you are right. Maybe I activated them by mistake but I think they are not related to the services that I use