# How to retrieve all resources created by aws user account

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have one AWS user account which is/was used to created some resources for my applications earlier, Now i want to delete that AWS account, so want to list down all resources created from this account or any resources which are linked with this account to analyze impact of deleting aws account.

All resources are in one region only.

Comment: [Good to read][1]

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391817/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-resources-in-aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single command that can list all resources in an AWS Account.

You would need to use the AWS management console or makes API calls to each service, in each region, to retrieve a listing of created resources.

A good place to start would be the **billing console**, which can show you which services have been consumed in which region. You can then go to each of those services and regions to view the resources. (Not all resources incur a charge, so they might not appear on the billing console. For example, security groups are not charged.)