# Listing all AWS resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, resources

How do I list all AWS tagged and untagged resources and delete only cost consumable resources, as soon as the resource reaches the cost threshold?

Comment: There is no provided method for obtaining a list of _all_ resources. You would need to write a script to loop through all services in all regions. You should be able to find plenty of examples on the web where people have already written such scripts (eg [JohannesEbke/aws_list_all: List all your AWS resources, all regions, all services.](https://github.com/JohannesEbke/aws_list_all)).

Comment: **See Also**: [Is there a way to list all resources in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44391817/1366033)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of resources using AWS Config or its CLI.

> aws configservice list-discovered-resources

You can write custom script or lambda along with CloudWatch events to get the cost and usage for this specific API.

Follow this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ce/index.html).

Comment: AWS Config is an expensive service, is there a better way to solve this issue?  Also can the list of resources (which are exceeding the cost) be extracted and deleted in a child account which is part of an AWS Organisation?

Comment: I think you can use this cli command to discover all resources of a region: aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources --region us-west-2

Comment: And it's not possible to automatically list resources. But you'll need to write custom script using AWS Cost and Usage APIs.

Comment: Is there a way through lambda to delete resources automatically? (which are exceeding the cost) ?

Comment: Yes, you can either use aws-sdk in Nodejs or boto3 in Python to automate this task with Lambda.