# How is possible to get all lists and resources of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I would like to get the list of resources, created on AWS and sort them via the creation date.

Answer (score 0):

This was answered in [Is there a way to list all resources in AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391817/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-resources-in-aws).

Unfortunately there is not. You need to make a separate API call to each service in each region.