# Is there a way to generate a report about an AWS Instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking to generate a report about my AWS environment: Frontend uses S3 and the Backend uses an EC2 instance. Is there any way I can export a report about the details of my set up? Tks

Comment: What do you want to have in the report? The approach depends on it.

Comment: The build infrastructure details of the Environment. What might usually be included in a Bill of Materials.

Comment: Look @ this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391817/is-there-a-way-to-list-all-resources-in-aws) query.

Comment: Hi yes, I think that's fine for  now. I certainly never knew about that. Thanks for the info.